# evancz/url-parser and multiple query parameters

Tags: elm

I'm not sure how to get access to multiple query parameters.

There is no example in the [source code](https://github.com/evancz/url-parser/blob/0607cf332c6116be72e8f1a4d9b7caba498f3e1a/src/UrlParser.elm) for that.

I know how to get one query parameter using `<?>`:

```elm
routeParser : Url.Parser (Route -> a) a
routeParser =
    Url.oneOf
        [ Url.map HomeRoute Url.top
        , Url.map SettingsRoute (Url.s "settings" <?> Url.stringParam "sortBy")
        ]


parseLocation : Location -> Route
parseLocation location =
    location
        |> Url.parsePath routeParser
        |> Maybe.withDefault NotFoundRoute
```

With `parsePath` I can get `Dict` with query params, but Is there an elegant way using `<?>`?

Edit:

I've used [this example](https://github.com/evancz/url-parser/issues/23#issuecomment-266169129) in `elm-repl`:

```elm
> parsePath (s "blog" <?> stringParam "search" <?> stringParam "sortBy") (Location "" "" "" "" "" "" "/blog" "?search=cats&sortBy=name" "" "" "")
-- TYPE MISMATCH --------------------------------------------- repl-temp-000.elm

The 1st argument to function `parsePath` is causing a mismatch.

5|   parsePath (s "blog" <?> stringParam "search" <?> stringParam "sortBy") (Location "" "" "" "" "" "" "/blog" "?search=cats&sortBy=name" "" "" "")
                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Function `parsePath` is expecting the 1st argument to be:

    Parser (Maybe String -> Maybe String) (Maybe String)

But it is:

    Parser (Maybe String -> Maybe String -> Maybe String) (Maybe String)

Hint: It looks like a function needs 1 more argument.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can chain `<?>` together for multiple query parameters. Let's say your `SettingsRoute` also expected a `pageNumber` integer argument:

```elm
type Route
    = ...
    | SettingsRoute (Maybe String) (Maybe Int)
```

Your parser could then look like this:

```elm
Url.map SettingsRoute (Url.s "settings" <?> Url.stringParam "sortBy" <?> Url.intParam "pageNumber")
```

The query parameters from the incoming URL don't need to be in the same order as your map statement. The following example will give the same results for the above route:

```elm
settings?sortBy=name&pageNumber=3
settings?pageNumber=3&sortBy=name
```

**Edit**

You added an example from the REPL. The problem you are experiencing in the REPL is because you aren't mapping correctly to something that takes two parameters. Consider this example for the REPL:

```elm
> type alias SearchParams = { search : Maybe String, sortBy : Maybe String }
> parsePath (map SearchParams (s "blog" <?> stringParam "search" <?> stringParam "sortBy")) (Location "" "" "" "" "" "" "/blog" "?search=cats&sortBy=name" "" "" "")
Just { search = Just "cats", sortBy = Just "name" }
    : Maybe.Maybe Repl.SearchParams
```

Comment: I looks like it doesn't work in elm-repl. And that is why I thought chaining doesn't work. Updated question

Comment: I updated my answer to address your REPL issue. The original answer still stands, the problem is with how you are trying to use it in the REPL.